# Portal 2 - What are these strange floating boxes in the void?

Tags: portal-2, source-engine

In Portal 2, when I no clip through the world, I sometimes notice these unreachable boxes, and different shapes floating in the middle of nowhere.

[image]

*This map was made by valve, and you can see these boxes on almost every single map*

---

From experience with the Portal 2 Authoring tools, I know that no props, objects, functions can exist in the void, and have to be sealed in walls, or you get a "leak". This is said to be because the game engine needs to separate the void from the playable area.

Is there any actual benefit to putting logic outside of the map, as having it inside does not interfere with playability at all? If I was to make a map, why would putting logic outside benefit me in any way?

Comment: This might be something you'd want to ask http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead. Check the quesion's on-topicness beforehand, tough.

Comment: They are probably in skybox if you can't reach them- or they are in void.

Comment: maybe not applicable to portal 2, but in other source games these objects are used with the sky boxes.

Comment: @ardaozkal They are in the void. Most portal maps (like this one) do not need a skybox as it is indoors. These boxes were accessed by noclipping through a wall to the void

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, Portal 2 doesn't *need* a skybox.  But when working with the Source engine, it is better to put a skybox in, even if it has little to nothing in it.

Comment: @Jaketr00 I found out now that decompiling a map with bspsource shows that 1 of the boxes had a "light origin" in it. I dont know what that is

Comment: @Jaketr00 That depends on the map.  There are maps in Portal 2 that let you see out into the facility and would have a skybox because of it.

Comment: @JohnSmith Did you check what types of entities they are?

Answer (score 1):

Those boxes are source for the Hammer Editor, like...
I think they put settings spawns to teleport and ect. inside

So they put a cube inside the box, the reason is because you don't want a cube in your map for no reason, I know they come out from a box but how you get another cube if the other cube gets destroyed?
Thats exactly this.

If your cube gets destroyed it calls another cube from those unreachable boxes. Inside one of them there is a cube, this cube is used to be a template.

If a cube is a template you can spawn other templates, which will result another cube.

Comment: I doubt that this is the case of a cube dispenser. Those have shafts on the walls of test chambers. The map devs could've also put the logic inside the test chamber.

Comment: A cube is inside there, which is supposed to be a template, one  of them is also a player spawn point